# PHP JSON results using jQuery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following PHP code that created a JSON request from posted form fields.

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['data']['Affiliate'])) { //Where ['data']['Affiliate'] is an array of posted field names of the form.
    $data = $_POST['data'];

    $base = 'https://api.whatever.com/Api?';

    $params = array(
        'Format' => 'json'
        ,'account' => $data['Affiliate']
    );

    $url = $base . http_build_query( $params );
    $result = file_get_contents( $url );
    $result = json_decode( $result );

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $result );
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

`print_r( $result )` prints the following.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [request] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Format] => json
            [account] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [country] => US
                    [address1] => asdasd
                    [city] => asdasd
                    [zipcode] => asdasd
                    [phone] => asdasd
                )
        )

    [response] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => -1
            [data] => 
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [err_code] => 3
                            [err_msg] => A user already exists with this email address.
                            [attribute_name] => Email
                            [publicMessage] => User account or user is not valid.
                        )
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [err_code] => 1
                            [err_msg] => City cannot be blank.
                            [attribute_name] => city
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

How can i use JQuery Ajax to achieve the same results and print out the array of errors in `<li>` tags.

Comment: The same way you would use [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to make any other request? What part of the process is giving you problems?

Comment: @Dcoder, do i use ajax type as JSON. Do i serialize the form. How do i sort thru the error array. I just need some jquery help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you don't decode the JSON to a PHP object as you did here, but keep the pure JSON, give that to your AJAX request and then do the decoding client-side (I believe there is a special jquery ajax function that gets and decodes it already for you. See Ravi's answer for that)

But if you don't want to do this: why don't you access the fields of the object you got from `json_decode()`?
I believe that `$result->$response->$errors` is the array of errors you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
var errorsArr='';
var affiliate='';
//affiliate is your data of $data['Affiliate'] which you can get using jquery or js..
$.ajax({
    url:'https://api.whatever.com/Api?'
    data:{Format: 'json',account : affiliate},
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
      errorsArr=data.response.errors;
    }
  }
});
```

you will get all errors in errorsArr. it is a json array you can iterate it for desired output

Comment: `data:{Format: 'json',account => affiliate,` How do all the form fields gets stringified. How does `account => affiliate` in data works.

Comment: @hedhud you need to use json_encode($result) before you send it back to the server. That's how you get the JSON stringified.

Comment: you can serialize the form in a variable (affiliate).